# Models in the Django admin

Tags: django

I'm pretty new in Django. I'm trying to work with Django admin.

This is my code

```
 list_phone = (('1', 'Iphone 2G'),
           ('2', 'Iphone 3G'),
          ('3' , 'Iphone 3GS'),
          ('4' , 'Iphone 4'),
          ('5' , 'Iphone 4S'),
          ('6' , 'Iphone 5'),
          ('7' , 'Iphone 5C'),
          ('8' , 'Iphone 5S'),
          ('9' , 'Iphone 6'),
          ('10' , 'Iphone 6_Plus'),
 )

class Iphone(models.Model):
   phone_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, choices = list_phone)
 date_public = models.DateTimeField('public date')
 advantage = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
 defect = models.CharField(max_length =100)
 price = models.FloatField(default = 0)

 def __unicode__(self):
     return self.phone_name
```

So, in action, it return '1'. How can I return 'Iphone 2G'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In django models there are automatically created methods [get_FOO_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) (FOO should be replaced with your field name). When called, they will return value from 2nd position for fields with choices.